# How do I permanently delete emails from the server and keep a local copy? (IMAP, Outlook 2010)

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, imap

I've set up an IMAP account with outlook 2010.

When I delete emails in Outlook they are moved to the 'deleted' folder on the server. However, due to limited space I would like to keep a local copy of the deleted email messages and remove them from the server.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Select all of the deleted messages in "deleted items" > move them to a new folder say "To be archived". Next go to FILE > Cleanup Tools > Archive. Select "To be archived" folder , select items older than "today", point to a place on your hard disk and click OK. After the archive is complete you can remove "deleted items".

Whenever you need to open your archive, just go to FILE > Open > Open data file > Navigate to your archive > OK. These messages will appear at the bottom of the mailbox tree on the left.

That's all.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to automatically send deleted files to a specified folder?

Comment: Don't know about automatic redirection, but you can move your "trash" directly to your "To be archived" folder if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

In answer to the question "*Is there a way to automatically send deleted files to a specified folder?* " - yes there is - or at least, a way to achieve this same thing - using autoarchive.

In the properties of the Deleted Item folder, go into Auto Archive, and set it to move to an Archive PST. Choose how many days old as a cut-off. Then, set Auto Archive to run frequently ( I have it set to run daily without prompting).

I do this at work because their Exchange policy deletes everything over 7 days old from Deleted Items, so I save them to the archive PST.

P.S. One other tip, to backup your Archive PST if it is large, try "Mailstore Home" - it creates backups that are incremental in effect - by splitting its backup output into files of about 10MB so that you don't have to re-copy the existing ones.